# Nested routing not working for me in vuejs application

Tags: vue.js, nested-routes

Hey Guys I'm pretty new to vue.js. And I want to make routing with sub routes. I read almost every post but can't do it. Something's wrong in my Code. So please help me if you can. Here is my codes an templates.

Router.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Game from '../components/game/Game.vue'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'
import Main from '../views/Main.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

const routes = [
  // {
  //   path: '/game',
  //   name: 'Game',
  //   component: Game,
  //   props: true
  // },
  {
    path: '/main',
    component: Main,
    props: true,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'game',
        name: 'game',
        component: Game,
        props: true
      },
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home,
        props: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login,
    props: true
  }
]

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

App.vue

```js
<template>

  <div id="app">

    <router-view></router-view>

  </div>

</template>
```

Main.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <Loader v-if="!userData.name"/>
    <Header :showUserInfoHandler="showUserInfoHandler" :userData="userData" :homeIsActive="isHomeActive"/>
    <section class="gamePage" ref="resizeArea">
      <div class="leftSide" ref="leftSide">
        <div class="topSide" ref="topSide">
          <router-view :width="gameTableWidth" :height="gameTableHeight" :homeActiveHandler="homeActiveHandler" name="rout"></router-view>
        </div>
        <div id="resizerY" ref="resizerY" @mousedown="dragMouseDown($event, false)"></div>
        <div class="bottomSide" ref="bottomSide">
          <Messages v-if="showMessages" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="resizerX" ref="resizerX" @mousedown="dragMouseDown($event, true)"></div>
      <div class="rightSide" ref="rightSide">
        <SideBar class="sidebar"/>
      </div>
    </section>
    <UserDetails
      v-if="showUserInfo"
      :userData="userData"
      :closeUserDet="closeUserDet"
      :positions="userDetPositions"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

"/main/game" is same as "/main". so please help me. As I said I have seen almost every post and tutorial. But somethings wrong with my code and I cant'f figure out what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have named your view:

```
<router-view ... name="rout"></router-view>
```

and are trying to render `game` with that router-view, and first of all, the names do not match. Named views should be set up like [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#named-views), where in sample there are named views `a` and `b`:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        default: Foo,
        a: Bar,
        b: Baz
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

I think you are not looking for named views in this case (?), so removing `name="rout"` from your router view should solve your issue.